# Why is the DefaultIndex setting not working when executing a search query in Elasticsearch using NEST?"

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200")).DefaultIndex("product");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest(){Size =10000,};
var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<dynamic>(searchRequest);
var q = searchResponse.Hits.ToList()[0].Index;
```

[Code DeubgMode
Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RTj8.png)

As shown in the image, I have set the DefaultIndex to 'products', but I'm still retrieving data from the index 'kibana_sample_data_ecommerce'. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding something, as I thought that setting the DefaultIndex in the ElasticClient would restrict the search to that specific index only.

Additionally, my NEST version is 7.17.5, and the Elasticsearch version is 8.9.0. I'm unsure if this issue is related to a version mismatch, as I am using the latest versions for both.

Currently, this is not a serious issue. If I specify the 'products' index in the SearchRequest, it still meets my requirements. I just want to understand if I've misunderstood the actual use of DefaultIndex.